# Make result letters bold as I type in searchbox

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I am using Opencart v2.2.0. Search box is autocomplete and that part is alright. But now I need to make letters bold as I type in the search box.

Example:
 The user starts typing "some", and as he types, the results are:

**some**thing

awe**some**

etc.

NOTICE: The words "something" and "awesome" are just an example, in real time I do not know what search terms would user type in.

So far I have this code, but as I am not really a js/jquery expert, I need help implementing the upper request. Thank you all.

```
 //<![CDATA[

function doLiveSearch( ev, keywords ) {

    if( ev.keyCode == 38 || ev.keyCode == 40 ) {
        return false;
    }   

    $('#autosearch_search_results').remove();
    updown = -1;

    if( keywords == '' || keywords.length < 2 ) {
        return false;
    }
    keywords = encodeURI(keywords);

    $.ajax({url: $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=module/autosearch/ajax_asr&keyword=' + keywords, dataType: 'json', success: function(result) {
        if( result.length > 0 ) {
            var eList = document.createElement('ul');
            eList.id = 'autosearch_search_results';
            var eListElem;
            var eLink;
            var eImage;

            for( var i in result ) {
                eListElem = document.createElement('li');
                eLink = document.createElement('a');

            if( (result[i].thumb) != '' )
            {
                eImage = document.createElement('img');
                eImage.src = result[i].thumb;
                eLink.appendChild(eImage);                  

            }
// name
var el_span = document.createElement('name');
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(result[i].name);
    eLink.appendChild(el_span);
    el_span.appendChild(textNode);

// model
            if( (result[i].model) != '' )
            {
var el_span = document.createElement('model');
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(result[i].model);
    eLink.appendChild(el_span);
    el_span.appendChild(textNode);
            }

                if( typeof(result[i].href) != 'undefined' ) {
                    eLink.href = result[i].href;
                }
                else {
                    eLink.href = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/product&product_id=' + result[i].product_id + '&keyword=' + keywords;
                }
                eListElem.appendChild(eLink);

            if( (result[i].price) != '' )
            {

var br = document.createElement("br");
eLink.appendChild(br);

// special price
    if( (result[i].special) != '' )
        {

var el_span = document.createElement('special-price');
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(result[i].special);
    eLink.appendChild(el_span);
    el_span.appendChild(textNode);
        }

// price
var el_span = document.createElement('price');
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(result[i].price);
    eLink.appendChild(el_span);
    el_span.appendChild(textNode);
            }

// quantity/stock
            if( (result[i].stock) != '' )
            {

var br = document.createElement("br");
eLink.appendChild(br);
eLink.appendChild( document.createTextNode(result[i].stock) );
            }

                eList.appendChild(eListElem);
            }
            if( $('#autosearch_search_results').length > 0 ) {
                $('#autosearch_search_results').remove();
            }

            //view all results
            if( (result[i].viewall) != '' )
            {
            eListElem = document.createElement('li');
            eLink = document.createElement('a');
                var el_span = document.createElement('viewall');
                var textNode = document.createTextNode(result[i].viewall);
                eLink.appendChild(el_span);
                el_span.appendChild(textNode);
                eLink.href = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/search&search=' + keywords;
            eListElem.appendChild(eLink);
            eList.appendChild(eListElem);
            }

            $('#search').append(eList);
        }
    }});

    return true;
}

function upDownEvent( ev ) {
    var elem = document.getElementById('autosearch_search_results');
    var fkey = $('#search').find('[name=search]').first();


    if( elem ) {
        var length = elem.childNodes.length - 1;

        if( updown != -1 && typeof(elem.childNodes[updown]) != 'undefined' ) {
            $(elem.childNodes[updown]).removeClass('highlighted');
        }

        // Up
        if( ev.keyCode == 38 ) {
            updown = ( updown > 0 ) ? --updown : updown;
        }
        else if( ev.keyCode == 40 ) {
            updown = ( updown < length ) ? ++updown : updown;
        }

        if( updown >= 0 && updown <= length ) {
            $(elem.childNodes[updown]).addClass('highlighted');

            var text = elem.childNodes[updown].childNodes[0].text;
            if( typeof(text) == 'undefined' ) {
                text = elem.childNodes[updown].childNodes[0].innerText;
            }

        }
    }

    return false;
}

var updown = -1;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search').find('[name=search]').attr('autocomplete', 'off'); //disable autocomplete

    $('#search').find('[name=search]').first().keyup(function(ev){
        doLiveSearch(ev, this.value);
    }).focus(function(ev){
        doLiveSearch(ev, this.value);
    }).keydown(function(ev){
        upDownEvent( ev );
    }).blur(function(){
        window.setTimeout("$('#autosearch_search_results').remove();updown=0;", 1500);
    });
    $(document).bind('keydown', function(ev) {
        try {
            if( ev.keyCode == 13 && $('.highlighted').length > 0 ) {
                document.location.href = $('.highlighted').find('a').first().attr('href');
            }
        }
        catch(e) {}
    });
});
//]]>
```

Answer (score 1):

just add a function that highlights all the searched text end run it on every text you add to your html:

```
function highlightQuery(string,searchQuery){
    if(!string){
        return "";
    }
    var expr = searchQuery;
    expr = expr.replace(/\s+/, "|",searchQuery);
    var regex = new RegExp(expr,"gi");
    return string.replace(regex, function($1){
        return '<span class="highlight">'+ $1 +'</span>';
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply. I am not sure I follow your instructions. I add this function to the upper.js file and then what?

Comment: I do not know what text will user type in, that was just an example to show you what should happen when user starts typing in (any) search term.

Comment: right but one the user typed in the search query you do now the query don't you? you are sending this query via ajax to your server to grab the results (in you case i guess it's "keywords"). And for every textNode you add (every time you add text in your results html) you run it through this function so instead of document.createTextNode(result[i].name) you do document.createTextNode(highlightQuery(result[i].name))

Comment: sry my bad, you cannot use Textnode to add html like taht, better in stead of creating an html element, then a textNode and then adding the node to the hmtl element you can just use el_span.innerHTML = highlightQuery(result[i].name)

Answer (score 0):

**We are trying to do the formatting part at javascript 
so that only display should be done at HTML part**

Execute the below function on typeahead ,and then you just need to display
the resultant array(  **formattedResult**  ) in HTML.

**formattedResult**  will contain the formatted text.

While displaying **formattedResult** array in HTML , put 2nd position text
in bold of each iterated item.

Please try following code:-

```
//argument types searchList(Array) and searchWord(String)
function formatResult(searchList, searchWord ){
 var formattedResult = [[]];

 for(var prop in searchList){
     if(searchList[prop].indexOf("some")!=-1)
        {
           var index= searchList[prop].indexOf(searchWord );


           var temp = [];

           temp.push(searchList[prop].substring(0,index));

           temp.push(searchWord.toUpperCase());


           temp.push(searchList[prop].substring(index + searchWord.length,
           searchList[prop].length));

           //console.log(temp);
           formattedResult.push(temp);

      }
     else{
        formattedResult.push(searchList[prop])
     }
   }
   return formattedResult;

}
```